# how to encode whitespace in mailto link to create a hyperlink

Tags: html, mailto

Im using outlook 2007, and want a hyperlink to a site in the body parameter of the mailtolink.

The link to the site has whitespaces in it. If i try to use %20, the whitespace gets rendered but the problem is in outlook, the part of the link thats actually a hyperlink is from the beginning uptil the first white space.

like this:

**www.my** site.aspx

So here the bold is the actual hyperlink.

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try +, but something is very wrong if your URL has a whitespace in it!

Comment: Its a sharepoint link to a list, and it keeps the list name as part of the link, and the list name has spaces in it, and I can't change the list name.

Answer (score 7):

Add `<` and `>` around the URL and outlook keeps the URL together ignoring  the spaces.